# is it possible to make a trial version of a php web based software?

Tags: php, security

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to implement licensing in php downloadable application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692831/how-to-implement-licensing-in-php-downloadable-application)

I am developing a web based software, i wonder if it's possible to protect a website developed with PHP from being copied, i mean i want to make sure that the user don't copy the software and sell it or give it to another person.

Comment: Control the "trial version installation" by allowing them to create a version on your server to test. However, once you give them the code, you're potentially wasting your time (and probably are anyway).

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Do these people have access to your server? If this is a web app where people only have access via a web browser, they don't have any access to your code, just the HTML it outputs.

Comment: See also:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408417/can-you-compile-php-code

Comment: @BenBrocka The Web App Could be installed On a local machine of the Customer,and Thank for everybody else :).

Comment: Ah, the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408417/can-you-compile-php-code/1408499#1408499 is particularly what you want then, I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is software that encrypts your code to unreadable code.

For example:
http://www.ioncube.com/
http://www.byterun.com/

You can encrypt your code for free (need to do it file by file) on http://www.byterun.com/free-php-encoder.php but it's not to hard to decrypt the free version.

If you can encrypt your source, you can check the date of the server, and if the date set in your config is older then 30 days, you can throw an exception that the trial has expired.

Comment: +1 for IonCube... I couldn't remember the name of it.  It is well supported by many hosts, but if you're trying to sell an application, your clients might not be too happy about it.

Comment: Obfuscation is not encryption!

Answer (score 2):

You can compile or obfuscate your PHP code:

http://www.phpcompiler.org/

Answer (score 0):

There are tools like sourceguardian and phpprotect that will do this for you.  Just google "protect php".

Answer (score 0):

You could host the software on your server but with that hosting all the route commands and functions, but all the customizability comes from the users computer. Then you have an interpreter and an .htaccess setup that routes all information through the interpreter. that uses CURL to get in touch of your software, and return the correct information. if you have some sort of auth on it, then you can provide expiration dates for certain users or information.

yes its slow, but it provides all the functionality with keeping your code secure, which should be enough to get the user to decide to buying it or not.